# Is it possible to save a imageview of an activity?

Tags: android, imageview, save, screenshot

I have a question: is it possible to save an imageview of an activity without seeing it?

For example, if I have 3 activities A, B & C, I want to save by making a print screen or other way an imageview in C activity when I'm in A or B activity.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for your light

Comment: No. A screen capture is only possible when there's a visible screen to capture in. Waht you could do in A or B is to use the same layout as use for C.

Comment: agree with Vyger. For more information about taking screenshots (also from the background) consult this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136121/android-how-to-take-screenshot-programatically

Comment: hmm... I think if you have the Bitmap of the ImageViews or the whole object of it, it could be possible