# I want to add GeoJson to mapbox mapsnapshot

Tags: java, android, mobile, mapbox

I have been trying to find an efficient way to show multiple views of a mapbox map, and I have landed on the mapbox snapshotter. However I have had little luck when trying to add a ***geojson string of coordinates*** to the snapshot.

I used the below code:

```
 int width  = myContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
 int height = (int) convertDpToPixel(200f, myContext);

 MapSnapshotter.Options snapShopOptions = new MapSnapshotter.Options(width, height);

 LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                .include(post.getPath().get(0))
                .include(post.getPath().get(post.getPath().size() - 1))
                .build();

 snapShopOptions.withRegion(bounds);

 snapShopOptions.withStyle(myContext.getString(R.string.outdoor_style));

 mapSnapshotter = new MapSnapshotter(myContext, snapShopOptions);

 mapSnapshotter.setStyleJson(String.valueOf(new Style.Builder()
               .fromUri("mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11")));

 mapSnapshotter.start(new MapSnapshotter.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(MapSnapshot snapshot) {
                Bitmap bitmapImage = snapshot.getBitmap();
                Glide.with(myContext).load(bitmapImage).into(holder.mapSnapShot);
            }
        });
```

**I have tried initializing a MapboxMap object and adding the geojson to that feature and then using the .getProjection(), but it still does not show the route.**

Can anyone help me solve this issue??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up contacting Mapbox support and as of now the feature is not supported. Their exact quote was `"Mapbox's MapSnapshotter does not support your use case, but it will once runtime styling is supported by the snapshotter."`

Support then pointed me to this post [Android Convert current screen to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294489/android-convert-current-screen-to-bitmap).

Hopefully if anyone was struggling similarly to me this will help save some time!