# MapBox: How to capture bitmap of map with polylines

Tags: mapbox, screenshot, mapbox-android

I used the MapSnapshotter to capture the bitmap of the map. However, I could only get the image of the base map but not the polylines that I have drawn over it, which is the running route of the user and is crucial to my project. Is there anyway to capture the map image together with the polylines?

I used a LineManager to draw my polylines.

Code below:

```
startSnapShot(mapboxMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds,
              mapView.getMeasuredHeight(),
              mapView.getMeasuredWidth());


--------------

private void startSnapShot(LatLngBounds latLngBounds, int height, int width) {
        mapboxMap.getStyle(style -> {
            if (mapSnapshotter == null) {
                // Initialize snapshotter with map dimensions and given bounds
                MapSnapshotter.Options options =
                        new MapSnapshotter.Options(width, height)
                                .withCameraPosition(mapboxMap.getCameraPosition())
                                .withStyle(style.getUri())
                                .withRegion(latLngBounds);

                mapSnapshotter = new MapSnapshotter(RunTracker.this, options);
            } else {
                // Reuse pre-existing MapSnapshotter instance
                mapSnapshotter.setSize(width, height);
                mapSnapshotter.setRegion(latLngBounds);
            }
            mapSnapshotter.start(snapshot -> passBitmap(snapshot.getBitmap()));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox's Android `MapSnapshotter` does not currently support capturing runtime styling added to the map. The image retrieved from `snapshot.getBitmap()` does not include any annotations added on the client side, such as with the `LineManager`.

You could instead add these polylines directly to the map style itself with [Mapbox Studio](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/overview/). Alternatively, you could use the suggested code in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294489/android-convert-current-screen-to-bitmap), which is not specific to Mapbox. If you pass the `Layout` containing your Mapbox map object to the `takeScreenShot` method, you should be able to generate a `Bitmap` containing your map and annotations added to said map with the `LineManager`.

Comment: The second method just gives a blank image of the map and does not capture anything. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431836/mapbox-capture-whole-screen-but-mapboxmap-turned-out-to-be-black).

Answer (score 0):

instead of MapSnappShotter use mapboxmap.snapshot like below code.
it return a bitmap wit all line and marker on map to you

```
 mMap.snapshot(new MapBoxMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) {
                
            }
        });
```