# Take screen captures for any activity in the background (not root)

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm doing some research for a client for auditing app and would like to know whether there is a way, without rooting the device, to take snapshots from a service in the background?

It should be able to take a snapshot of any activity in the foreground. Is there any programatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```
View rootView = MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);      
rootView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(this.screenWidth/*specify the width here*/, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(this.screenHeight/*specify the height here*/, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
rootView.layout(0, 0, rootView.getMeasuredWidth(), rootView.getMeasuredHeight()); 
rootView.buildDrawingCache(false);
Bitmap bmScreen = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
```

This code requires the activity to be in memory and in the foreground. Without root access and without modifying Android's source there is no way you can one can take a screenshot. I too researched a lot on it and this was the best I could come up with. In the end we ended up taking the screenshots on Activity's level. However, just in case you're open to root access, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184485) is the link on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you but I need to get it from a background service not from a foreground activity.

Comment: This code requires the activity to be in memory and in the foreground. Without root access and without modifying Android's source there is no way you can one can take a screenshot. I too researched a lot on it and this was the best I could come up with. In the end we ended up taking the screenshots on Activity's level. However, just in case you're open to root access, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20184485) is the link on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Please write this as an answer and I will choose it